# Gallery.php linking images

Tags: php, function, hyperlink, gallery, user-defined-functions

So the following link is to the gallery.php code

(https://github.com/JoomShaper/Helix-Joomla/blob/master/helixPlugin/shortcodes/gallery.php/)!

On line 58, I want to change the function to, link to the href inside the image (Which I will add to the image on the database side (Joomla)- I guess this is call a user-defined function?

I am new to this so I am not familiar with some of the terms.

If anyone can help, this is will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"On line 58, I want to change the function to, link to the href inside the image"

If by this you mean that you wish to change the value of the href attribute to point to the image then (as you can see at line #60) you can change

```
<?php echo ($modal=='yes')? '#modal-' . $key . '':'#' ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $item['src']; ?>
```

This will change what actually happens when the user clicks on the anchor.

What you do with the value of $item['src'] then depends on you. And yes you are probably going to use a user defined function to store the value in the database but this doesn't mean that you must use one.

Comment: Perfect! ok, I'm slowly understanding. How do I change the value of $item['src'], so that when a user clicks that, a website opens.